# Is this an exact sequence split?

Tags: exact-sequence

I am reading about split exact sequence and come out with a question. Consider the following sequence.

$0 \to A\to A\oplus B\oplus C\to B\to0$

It seems to me that it's exact. So, is it an split exact sequence?

To be more explicit, just set $A\to A\oplus B\oplus C$ to be $a\to (a,0,0)$, and $ A\oplus B\oplus C\to B $ to be $(0,b,0)\to b$.

Comment: No its not exact if C is nonzero.

Comment: For this kind of question, you really should say explicitly what the maps $A\oplus B\oplus C\to B$ and $A\to A\oplus B\oplus C$ are. Otherwise it's impossible to determine whether the sequence is exact or not, and whether it is split or not.

Comment: @Wuestenfux- Why is it not exact?

Comment: The kernel of $A\oplus B\oplus C \to B$ is $A\oplus C$. The image of $A\to A\oplus B\oplus C$ is $A$. These are the same iff $C=0$

Comment: Oh, I had lost my mind. Thank you for your patience.